# google_maps_flutter and AndroidX migration

Tags: flutter

I am working on a project that requires google_maps_flutter package. When selecting the option Run -> Flutter run in Release Mode I receive:

---

The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See  for more information on the problem and how to fix it.

---

If I follow the documentation to Avoiding AndroidX from the official page:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#avoiding-androidx
I have the following issue:
The last available version pre AndroidX for google_maps_flutter is 0.1.0
Seems that this version does not exist.

Log Error:
Because  depends on google_maps_flutter 0.1.0 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the issue because the package version is too old.

Latest version for google_maps_flutter is 0.5.13

Follow instructions which are mentioned in the Google maps flutter package  [here](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

Follow instructions from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility) to migrate your flutter app to AndroidX.